# How to pass an array of structures using JNA

Tags: java, arrays, winapi, jna, structure

I referenced another stackoverflow article "How do I map a pointer to an array of structures in JNA" to come up with the following code to enumerate Windows service dependencies.

Structure and function declarations:

```
static class SERVICE_STATUS extends Structure {
    public int dwServiceType;
    public int dwCurrentState;
    public int dwControlsAccepted;
    public int dwWin32ExitCode;
    public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
    public int dwCheckPoint;
    public int dwWaitHint;
    public SERVICE_STATUS(){}
}

static class ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS extends Structure {
    public ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS(){ }

    public WString lpServiceName;
    public WString lpDisplayName;
    SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus;
}

boolean EnumDependentServicesW(Pointer hService, int serviceState, ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatuses, int size, IntByReference bytesNeeded, IntByReference servicesReturned);
```

If there is only one service dependency, the following code works:

```
IntByReference bytesNeeded = new IntByReference();
IntByReference numberOfServices = new IntByReference();
Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus = new Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS();
Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS[] serviceStatuses = (Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS[]) serviceStatus.toArray(1);

if (!advapi32.EnumDependentServicesW(serviceHandle, Advapi32.SERVICE_ACTIVE, null, 0, bytesNeeded, numberOfServices)) {
    if (advapi32.EnumDependentServicesW (serviceHandle, Advapi32.SERVICE_ACTIVE, serviceStatuses[0], bytesNeeded.getValue(), bytesNeeded, numberOfServices)) {
        for(int i = numberOfServices.getValue() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            logger.debug("Service Name: " + serviceStatuses[i].lpServiceName.toString());
    }
}
```

If there are 2 service dependencies, I get a NullPointerException for lpServiceName in the logger.debug call:

```
IntByReference bytesNeeded = new IntByReference();
IntByReference numberOfServices = new IntByReference();
Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus = new Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS();
Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS[] serviceStatuses = (Advapi32.ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS[]) serviceStatus.toArray(2);

if (!advapi32.EnumDependentServicesW(serviceHandle, Advapi32.SERVICE_ACTIVE, null, 0, bytesNeeded, numberOfServices)) { 
    if (advapi32.EnumDependentServicesW (serviceHandle, Advapi32.SERVICE_ACTIVE, serviceStatuses[0], bytesNeeded.getValue(), bytesNeeded, numberOfServices)) {
        for(int i = numberOfServices.getValue() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            logger.debug("Service Name: " + serviceStatuses[i].lpServiceName.toString());
    }
}
```

The numberOfServices value for the code above is 2, as expected. I'm trying to pass the structure array instead of a pointer because I want JNA to do the memory synching. How should I be passing/using the array of structures?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `EnumDependentServices`,

> **lpServices [out, optional]**
>
> > A pointer to an array of
> >     ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS structures that receives the name and service
> >     status information for each dependent service in the database. ***The
> >     buffer must be large enough to hold the structures, plus the strings
> >     to which their members point.***

You're pretty much ignoring the required buffer size as reported by `bytesNeeded`.  You should use the `bytesNeeded` value to create a `Memory` instance of the requisite size, then use that `Memory` instance to create a new `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` instance, instead of creating the structure independently of the required buffer size.

Comment: Thank you, @technomage, for your input. I can allocate the memory to an ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS instance, but I don't quite understand how this would work. BytesNeeded is the total size of all structures in the array plus the strings that the structures point to. So, if I manually allocate all memory to a single ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS instance, how does the array of ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS structures get populated (and how I would access the array elements after returning from EnumDependentServices)?

Comment: Once you know the memory required, create a `Memory` instance of that size, use it to initialize an `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` instance, and call `toArray` on that.  `Structure` has a constructor that takes a `Pointer` value; use that to overlay your structure on your newly allocated `Memory`.  Once you've called `toArray` on the base `Structure`, JNA knows how to keep track of it and synch all the array members across the native method call.

Comment: I finally got it returning all dependencies by updating to JNA 3.3.0, creating a Memory instance and using that to create ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS. THANK YOU @technomage! I'm still trying to figure out how to determine the size to use for toArray because we don't know how many service dependencies there are until after the second call to EnumDependentServices, yet we need to do toArray before the second call...